# Rails cookies not working right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Rails is setting and returning a remember_token cookie like this:

```
= cookies[:remember_token] 
= value6c69b17681d2bf316f8eexpiresThu Jun 10 14:55:00 -0400 2010
```

In other words, when I'm calling the cookie I don't just get the value. Why is this?

I am setting the cookie as follows:

```
cookies[:remember_token] = { :value => @user.remember_me, :expires => 1.year.from_now}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I've just tried this locally and here it works the way you're expecting it to. i.e. `cookies[:cookie_name]` returns just the value of the cookie. So there must be something else going on in your code.. can you post some more of the surrounding code from the controller actions? Can you print the value of `@user.rememeber_me` immediately before you store it in the cookie - what should it be? just a boolean value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this problem as well.  I'm on Rails 2.3.8.  Using cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = value works, however (with proper expiration set).  Looks like it is related to the cookie add-ons included in 2.3.6 http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0200e20f148c96afceeebc4da7b5985643f9f707